# "Быть может" в данном предложении - это вводное слово или сказуемое?

Tags: вводные-слова

Считается ли это предложение простым?

> Быть может, батюшка войдёт.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Быть может, батюшка войдёт.*

*Батюшка войдёт* — грамматическая основа.
[*Быть может*](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_417) — вводное сочетание со значением "вероятно", "возможно". Оно не является членом предложения (к нему нельзя задать вопрос, но можно изъять из предложения без потери смысла), в произношении выделяется интонационно, на письме — запятой.

Это простое двусоставное предложение, нераспространённое, осложнённое вводной конструкцией.

Вот, думаю, самое известное "быть может".

*Я вас любил: любовь еще, **быть может,**

В душе моей угасла не совсем;

Но пусть она вас больше не тревожит;

Я не хочу печалить вас ничем.*
А. С. Пушкин

[Общая структура простого предложения](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/700-11_obschaya_struktura_prostogo_predlozheniya_grammaticheskaya_osnova.html)